# Is there a way to save values of variables from each iteration of for loops

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I'm very new to programming so forgive if this question is a bit stupid. Anyway I'm making this console program that is supposed to calculate total damage per hit after bonus damage is applied.
Example: damage is 100 per hit with 0 initial bonus damage that increases by 50 per hit. The program is supposed to calculate the total damage after N amounts of hits.

This is what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
int n;
int bonusDam = 0;
int i;
int b;
int a;
scanf("%d", &n);

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    b = 100 + bonusDam;
    bonusDam = bonusDam + 50;
    printf("Hit %d : %d\n", i, b);
}

    return 0;
}
```

I figured out how to calculate the bonus damage but not the total damage after N amounts of hits.
Is a for loop a good idea or no? If i input 3 it'll output "100, 150, 200" but what I want to do is to add them all up like "100 + 150 + 200 = 450" Where in the end the console only shows "450"

Comment: Hint: use meaningful variable names. There is somewhat more typing, but the code is so much easier to read.

Comment: You already know how to do `bonusDam = bonusDam + 50;` so why don't you know how to do `totalDam = totalDam + b;`?

Comment: @user253751 I already did that but it didn't work

Comment: @Jabberwocky oh is it not readable?

Comment: how didn't it work?

Comment: @user253751 Nvm it actually worked. I guess I only did the logic in my head and I thought it didn't make any sense. I got confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to add that there is no need for a for loop to calculate the final result

```
int b = 100 * n + 50 * n * (n - 1) / 2;
```

Comment: Wow, I was needlessly overthinking things huh

Comment: Thanks, I was simply using this summation formula to add up the bonus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is to set `b = 0;` right before the loop and replace

`b = 100 + bonusDam;`

with

`b = b + 100 + bonusDam;`

This will effectively turn b into the total damage, by accumulating the value after every iteration. By moving `printf("Hit %d : %d\n", i, b);` outside of the loop, you should get the result you want.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I was bashing my head against the wall with this for hours so you definitely made my day.